# Integrating Cocos2d-x v2.2.5 into Marmalade

Tags: c++, xcode6, cocos2d-x, marmalade

I've changed this post from a question regarding an error I was getting (which BTW received no answers) into actual instructions on HOW-TO integrate cocos2d-x version 2.2.5 into Marmalade (because none could be found online). This should prove valuable to new Marmalade developers and experienced developers alike.  Marmalade comes with an older and (oh dear, a) BETA version of Cocos2dx (version 2.1.0 Beta3 as of this post) and we want to upgrade that.  These instructions apply to Mac OSX systems but a similar approach (minus directory soft-linking) can be applied to Win32 systems as well.

1. Assuming you've already downloaded and installed Marmalade.
2. Download Cocos2dx version 2.2.5 (or the latest 2.x branch)
3. Open the `Applications` folder (from GUI) and scroll down to Marmalade, right-click on Marmalade and choose `Show Package Contents`.
4. Drill down the following path `./Contents/modules/third_party/`
5. Rename the `cocos2dx` directory to `cocos2dx_2.1.0_beta3` (*you can tell what version of cocos2dx came with Marmalade by opening the .`/cocos2dx/cocos2dx/` folders and viewing the `cocoos2d.cpp` file.*)
6. Create a new folder called `cocos2dx_2.2.5`.
7. Copy the following folders from your cocos2dx 2.2.5 download: `cocos2dx, CocosDenshion, extenstions, external, licenses, scripting, tools`.
8. Paste those into the new `cocos2dx_2.2.5` folder.
9. Open Terminal and `cd` into `/Applications/Marmalade.app/Contents/modules/third_party`
10. Create a soft-link to the new `cocos2dx_2.2.5` directory: `ln -s cocos2dx_2.2.5/ cocos2dx` (*note: for Win32 users, simply rename the new directory to `cocos2dx`*).

Performing a `ls -l` under `/Applications/Marmalade.app/Contents/modules/third_party` should now yield something that looks similar to the following:

```
drwxr-xr-x@  8 user  admin  272 Oct  1 08:35 Photon
drwxr-xr-x@  6 user  admin  204 Oct  1 08:35 c-ares
lrwxr-xr-x   1 user  admin   15 Nov  5 23:32 cocos2dx -> cocos2dx_2.2.5/   <-- soft-link
drwxr-xr-x@  9 user  admin  306 Oct  1 08:35 cocos2dx_2.1.0_beta3          <-- this
drwxr-xr-x   9 user  admin  306 Nov  5 23:28 cocos2dx_2.2.5                <-- this
drwxr-xr-x@  7 user  admin  238 Oct  1 08:35 curl
drwxr-xr-x@  8 user  admin  272 Oct  1 08:35 expat
drwxr-xr-x@  6 user  admin  204 Oct  1 08:35 gaf
drwxr-xr-x@ 11 user  admin  374 Oct  1 08:35 jsoncpp
drwxr-xr-x@  8 user  admin  272 Oct  1 08:35 libjpeg
drwxr-xr-x@  6 user  admin  204 Oct  1 08:35 libpng
drwxr-xr-x@  8 user  admin  272 Oct  1 08:35 lua
drwxr-xr-x@  7 user  admin  238 Oct  1 08:35 ode
drwxr-xr-x@ 12 user  admin  408 Oct  1 08:35 openquick
drwxr-xr-x@ 12 user  admin  408 Oct  1 08:35 openssl
drwxr-xr-x@  7 user  admin  238 Oct  1 08:35 sqlite
drwxr-xr-x@  6 user  admin  204 Oct  1 08:35 tiniconv
drwxr-xr-x@ 10 user  admin  340 Oct  1 08:35 tinyxml
drwxr-xr-x@  6 user  admin  204 Oct  1 08:35 twitcurl
drwxr-xr-x@  7 user  admin  238 Oct  1 08:35 zlib
```

From now on Marmalade will use the latest 2.x release of Cocos2dx.  Simply change the soft-link to point to a newer version when it comes out, or an older version if you have problems.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This site is all about the questions and answers format. You should keep your questions questions. Don't convert them to "answers". If you find the solution yourself, then post it as an answer to your question, but do not edit it into the question itself!

Comment: @Kaiserludi I know how the site works.

Answer (score 0):

To do something in a more Marmalade friendly way, I would suggest the following:

1. DO NOT place this code in your Marmalade SDK area - it just means that everytime a new SDK comes along you have to hack things, and it won't work out of the box.
2. Instead add something the following near the top of the mkb for the programs you want to use:

option module_path="whereeverIputcoscos/cocos2dx_2.2.5"

filling in the correct path. Not tried it, but this is the basic method. Once you've got that setup, it will use it without you having to fiddle with any SDK first.